# asp multiple detail records

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the need for off campus professors to view the attendance history of their students.
I am writing the application is classic asp with vbscript.

The database has a table for attendance but each student get a new record for each date the class meets and whether the attendance status was present late or absent.

My main procedure gathers the instructor id, which course he wants to view and returns a class roster (Distinct list of students) with the totals of each type of attendance status.

My final step is that they want to be able to click on the attendance status of a certain student and have those "n" amount of records shown.

I have looked at master / detail but all references say all the data has to be in a single row.  Repeating section does not seem to accept a second recordset which would be the same database base table, but filtered on student ID (passed as a URL parameter)for the course.

What is an approach that I can make this happen? One master record with a many detailed record relationship.

Comment: Are you asking about how to display existing data in a "drilldown" format, or are you asking how to set up the database?

Comment: I am asking to display in a drill down.  The sql table is already built with insert and update features populating the table (changing the table is not feasible).

Answer (score 0):

For transaction table, this schema might work
[date],[professorid],[studentid],[classid],[P],[L],[A]

With [P],[L],[A] as present,late and absence
then you need to create related student table

The rest of pages you need is a group by query based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

For the drilldown, you need two reports: one that has all the records for an instructor, and one that has all the details for a particular student with that instructor. If the columns you want to display are substantially the same between the two reports, then you can actually do this with a single .asp file, but I'll assume you want to have two files.

First, make the detail report. This should get a student ID and instructor ID from the querystring. Presumably, there should also be an academic year or period or some such time limit.

```vbs
<html><head><blah blah blah>
<%
dim AY, SID, IID, SQL '-etc.
AY = Request.Querystring("AY")
SID = Request.Querystring("S")
IID = Request.Querystring("I")
'- validate the inputs and assign default values as needed
%></head><body>
<%
SQL = "SELECT StudentName, Course, DateofClass, Attendance FROM AttendanceView"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE StudentID = " & SID & " AND InstructorID = " & IID
SQL = SQL & " AND AY = " & AY  '- or whatever other filters are needed
'- open a recordset and write it out, probably in a table
'- close recordset, close table
%></body></html>
```

Then, in the main report, when you're writing out the row for a student, make one of the columns a link to the detail report.

```vbs
'...
response.write "<td><a href='DetailReport.asp?I=" & rs("InstructorID")
response.write "&S=" & rs("StudentID") & "&AY=" & rs("AY") & "'"
response.write " title='Click to see details' target='_blank'>" 
response.write rs("TotalAttendance") & "</a></td>"
'---
```

I've put a target="_blank" on the link, but with a little bit of JavaScript, you can make the detail report come up in a popup window/overlay instead. Also, if you prefer, you can put the detail link in its own column, so instead of clicking, say, the total attendance number, the user would click a plus sign or the word "details" or an arrow or something. The basic idea is the still the same, though: put the identifying information for each row into the link, and then the detail report can read it from the querystring.